# What are the use cases for Out and In-Out Parameters in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, functions, parameter

I understand what Out and In-Out parameters are, but I can't seem to understand a good use case for them. Is it to make functions more descriptive? Or is there a practical benefit/need for using them?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not much benefit, it is just an alternative syntax.

These two definitions are the same:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f(IN a integer, OUT b integer, OUT c integer) RETURNS SETOF record

CREATE FUNCTION f(a integer) RETURNS TABLE (b integer, c integer)
```

There is one difference that may justify the syntax: with `OUT` parameters, you can use `RETURNS recurd` to create a function that is *not* table function, but returns several columns. That seems like a compelling use case to me.